# VBA - Find preceding html tag

Tags: html, vba, excel

Say I have HTML source that looks like this

```
<div id="book-info"> 
  <span class="title">Weather</span>
  <span class="title">Title Of Book</span>
  <p><a href="http://test.com?MMC_ID=34343">Buy Now</a></p>
</div>
```

What I need returned is "Title Of Book"

There are numerous instances of span class="title" but the one I need immediately precedes the only MMC_ID tag on the page, so I can use MMC_ID as a marker to get close to the span tag I need.

**Question:** How can I say "Grab the contents of the very first span tag to the left of MMC_ID?

The below code works sometimes, but there is a variable number of span tags on the page so it fails when that deviation occurs.

```
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value, False
    .Send
    htm.body.innerhtml = .ResponseText
End With

ExtractedText = htm.getElementById("book-info").getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText
```

Comment: If you can select the link element then you should be able to get to the span via `.parentElement.previousSibling`

Comment: Sorry if it seems obvious to you, but how would I grab the link element when the only unique identifier for that link is the fact the URL contains MMC_ID?  There could be other links in the book-info div as well (but they don't contain MMC_ID).

Comment: Get all the links and loop through and check the href for each - when you find the correct one you can work back from there.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
Text_1 = htm.getElementById("book-info").innerhtml
if instr(1, text_1, "MMC_ID ", vbTextCompare) > 0 then
   numb_spans = htm.getElementById("book-info").getElementsByTagName("span").length
   ExtractedText = htm.getElementById("book-info").getElementsByTagName("span")(-1 + numb_spans).innerText
else
end if
```

Comment: Is this taking the second to last SPAN element in the book-info div?

Comment: No, this is taking the last SPAN element.  Using your example above, numb_spans would equal "2".  Since the SPANs would actually be identified as "0" and "1", we used "-1 + numb_spans" to identify the last SPAN.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through all the spans and stop when the child of the next sibling of the next sibling is an anchor element and contains the proper text.

```
Sub test()

    Dim htm As HTMLDocument
    Dim ExtractedText As String
    Dim hSpan As HTMLSpanElement
    Dim hAnchor As HTMLAnchorElement

    Set htm = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "file://///99991-dc01/99991/dkusleika/My%20Documents/test.html", False
        .Send
        htm.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
    End With

    For Each hSpan In htm.getElementById("book-info").getElementsByTagName("span")
        On Error Resume Next
            Set hAnchor = hSpan.NextSibling.NextSibling.FirstChild
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not hAnchor Is Nothing Then
            If InStr(1, hAnchor.href, "MMC_ID", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                ExtractedText = hSpan.innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next hSpan

    Debug.Print ExtractedText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it always the *last* `span` element?  If so, just count how many elements

```
htm.getElementById("book-info").getElementsByTagName("span")
```

returns and grab the last one.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Imagine my clean HTML snippet in the middle of a massive page.  The only thing non-variable is the fact that my target SPAN immediately precedes the only instance of MMC_ID in the code.